# Please explain why my code can't replace redux-thunk

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-thunk

I have just finished reading redux fundamentals from the Redux doc. I now understand what happens underneath middleware functions and some of the other features of Redux. But I can't help questioning why you must use redux-thunk when processing async logic when you can just do:

```
const fetchSomething = async () => {
  const { data } = await axios('someEndpoint..');
  
  dispatch({ type: 'FETCH_SOME_DATA', payload: data.something });
}
```

and import this from components that need this logic. Somehow similar to action creators, though it doesn't return an action object.

EDIT: reviewing my question, I realized that `fetchSomething` function needs `dispatch` as parameter in order for it to be reused in different components.

Comment: Newer versions of redux have built in tooling around this type of thing (see https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createAsyncThunk). In fact they go beyond it with https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query. If you're on a greenfield project (or one with a small existing redux footprint), it's worth using. It includes caching and other niceities. Even with those, you need to inject the middleware they provide so that your store knows how to interpret those functions as actions.

Comment: @Derek Thanks for the comment Derek. After reading your comment, I am curious if redux-thunk is not used in real world applications anymore, but rather introduced as, sort of textbook for async handling in redux. There are already a number of relatively more easy-to-use middlewares that help async process. And I doubt redux-thunk will thrive in that competition.

Comment: redux toolkit uses redux-thunk behind the scenes, for createAsyncThunk anyway. It's definitely still valid and useful on its own though, and I use it in real world applications, eg in larger existing apps where refactoring that wouldn't be a priority at this time.